# Find all matches between delimeters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

How do I replace all `<p>` tags between delimiters? My text is

```
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
``text text...</p>
<p>text text...</p>
<p>text text ...``
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
``text text...</p>
<p>text text...</p>
<p>text text ...``
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
``text text...</p>
<p>text text...</p>
<p>text text ...``
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
```

I want to match all `<p>` tags between double backticks (``all p tags here``) as delimiters and replace them with empty string. I could match p tags if there is no other text outside delimiters using regex `/<\/?p>/i` but how can I match all p tags inside delimiters if  there is text and other p tags outside them.

Comment: Try using `''\w*/<\?p>/i\w*''`

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil This regex does not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$str = <<<EOD
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
``text text...</p>
<p>text text...</p>
<p>text text ...``
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
``text text...</p>
<p>text text...</p>
<p>text text ...``
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
``text text...</p>
<p>text text...</p>
<p>text text ...``
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
EOD;

$res = preg_replace_callback(
        '/``(?:(?!``).)*``/s', 
        function ($m) {
            return preg_replace('~</?p>~', '', $m[0]);
        },
        $str);
echo $res;
```

**Output:**

```
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
``text text...
text text...
text text ...``
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
``text text...
text text...
text text ...``
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
``text text...
text text...
text text ...``
<p>other text...</p>
<p>other text...</p>
```

Comment: Your code works for the text provided but there are multiple such blocks. I've edited the question. With this code the p tags I don't want to remove are also removed i.e. the all p tags from the first `` and last `` are removed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this amazing answer. Actually I figured out a way to achieve the same result by `preg_replace()` and a `for` loop but this is the best solution.